# Appeal to or on

Tags: nouns

What is the correct preposition for **appeal** in this sentence?

> "I am appealing against the court's decision of shop lifting **on/to** me.

I know ''appeal for'', ''appeal to works'', but I can't find the closest to this one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example sentence, the preposition relates to *decision*, not *appeal*.  It's difficult to say which is the most idiomatic choice because the entire sentence is not natural English.

You can appeal a *judgement* or a *decision* against you in a civil case.  In a criminal case you would have a *conviction* on a particular charge (like shoplifting), which you can appeal to a higher court.

> I am appealing my shoplifting conviction (to a particular court of appeals).

Comment: How about this: ''I am asking for an appeal against shoplifting conviction issued on me''? Is it ok now?

Comment: @JohnArvin  No, not really.  The phrasal verb is *appeal to*, as if you're reaching *towards* some higher authority for their support.  You're the one filing the appeal,  so you would always be *in favor* of the appeal (not *against* it).  Also you wouldn't *issue* a conviction.  Judges can issue *rulings* (in civil cases), but they *hand down* convictions.

Comment: You could say something like "I am appealing to the Fifth Circuit Court of Appeals to *reverse* my conviction for shoplifting that was *handed down* by Judge Wopner" ... but you can see it's pretty wordy.

Comment: Is it really ''to reverse **my** conviction...? Or should it be **the** instead?

Comment: @JohnArvin  either *my* or *the* is fine.